# non-resident alien e-filed using turbotax!

Tags: united-states, taxes, non-resident, f1-student-visa, turbotax

I am a non-resident alien and efiled using turbotax. Turbotax is generated form 1040-NR and a day after it stated that "Your 2015 Personal return was accepted!" 
The thing is everywhere mentioned that Turbotax doesn't support 1040-NR.
Is it a new future?
Is it ok that I did that as not-resident alien on F1-OPT Visa?
If not, should I mail the same forms as well?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [it looks like](https://turbotax.intuit.com/personal-taxes/irs-forms/) they added support for international students and scholars, as part of [their partnership with SprinTax](https://www.sprintax.com/non-resident-alien-tax-1040nr-turbotax.html).

They don't seem to have other forms essential for non-residents, like Schedule OI, so not sure how it works exactly.

Comment: Also, I believe that 1040-NR cannot be e-filed (and software that support it can only print it for you to mail), so I don't know what is going on here